# is there any sql command that lists the fields and counts how many times it appears in the table?

Tags: sql

I want to list the person's name and beside how many times this person got a 10.

Is there any command like this?

```
marcus gold 25 
julia silver 34
jason platinium 12
sarah bronze 45
```

Comment: Check out GROUP BY.

Comment: could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: You need to show us the source data as well as the desired output. Otherwise how can we tell you how to transform it correctly? And tag which database you're using, e.g. mysql, oracle, sql-server etc. This appears unrelated to php directly so I removed that tag. See also [ask]

Comment: P.s. if you want to count things, sql has a "COUNT" function! You can find lots of examples online very easily